# Can I safely run qbs with sudo?

Tags: qt, permissions, sudo, qmake, qbs

### Backstory (You can skip)

I am a bit more cautious these days when I am attempting to solve a what I presume to be a permissions limitation by running an application with `sudo`, ever since I ran this command:

```
sudo qtcreator
```

That completely borked my installation and caused many headaches for obvious reasons. Well, I am now playing around with a new (to me) Qt technology, `qbs` and I am encountering some errors which I think may be permissions related.

---

Before I risk many headaches, is it safe to run something like

```
sudo qbs setup-qt /usr/bin/qmake qt
```

without having to worry about breaking the integrity of `qbs`?

Comment: You could either edit the OS user settings for current user (to give permission to run as an admin with user-password and without sudo...)

Comment: Or you could edit the qbs/qtcreator file to have executable privileges (chmod) as an example for specific users

Comment: @DenisTsoi Are you talking about something like `visudo`?

Comment: That’s one method yes

Answer (score 1):

Running with sudo runs qbs as root, that's all. In particular, commands like qbs config or qbs setup-qt will alter the root user's settings, not your actual user's. And of course, the usual comments apply with regard to security: All commands run by qbs will run with admin rights. Personally, I don't see a reason to do this except when installing a project to a system location.

Comment: Basically, I was looking to install a project to a system location. Good to know.